# Who's ready for a Twitter + Bikes.SE contest? (UPDATE)

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE:** ***The contest is now live. See the rules [HERE](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/specialized-twitter-stack-exchange-giveaway-official-post).***

Starting Monday (10.17), Bicycles.StackExchange will be hosting a week-long promotion involving **3 prizes**:

- An awesome bike
- A basic bike
- A bag of bike tools

Check the official post Monday to see details about what's up for grabs.

**The Rules:**

- Retweet a TBA message included in the official post to enter your name
  into the contest.
- Include your Twitter name anywhere in your Bicycles.SE profile **AND**
  earn 10 points during the week (101 pts from linking an SE account excluded) to increase your chances of winning **3-fold**.

**The Terms:**

- Anyone anywhere is eligible.
- Winners will be picked at random with each winner eligible for only
  one prize.
- Prizes must be picked up in person at a licensed [TBA] dealer.
- Winners will be announced Monday, October 24.

***Any questions or concerns we can get out of the way before the contest kicks off?***

Comment: Has this contest started? I can't find the blog post.

Comment: @Richard - yes, you can find it here: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/547/specialized-twitter-stack-exchange-giveaway-official-post

Answer (score 2):

How do you include your twitter name in your profile? Do you just put it somewhere in the bio box like:

Twitter: @_richardg

Or, with a link:

Twitter: @[_richardg](http://twitter.com/_richardg)

Comment: Each of those formats will work.

Answer (score 1):

A question, not a concern: why does it have to be Twitter? Why not other social media also, e.g. people's blogs, Facebook status, etc.?

Comment: Twitter is involved here because it is easily trackable. Future contests may employ other means of sharing.