# Twitter + Stack Exchange Specialized Giveaway (UPDATE: We Have Winners!)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

---- *This contest is now closed* ----

You [were warned](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/545/whos-ready-for-a-twitter-bikes-se-contest). The bikes giveaway is now officially on...

[image]
*(Note: This giveaway is not sponsored by Specialized.)*

**The Prizes:**

- First: A [Specialized Tricross Sport](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCProduct.jsp?spid=62013&scid=1101&scname=Road)
- Second: A [Specialized Sirrus](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCProduct.jsp?spid=61562&scid=1102&scname=Multi%20Use)
- Third: A [Specialized Starter Kit](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=64066)

**The Rules:**

- Retweet [**THIS**](http://twitter.com/#!/StackHQ/status/125969317165674497) to enter the contest.
- Include your Twitter handle anywhere in your Bicycles.StackExchange
  profile.
- Earn 10 rep points **[across the Bicycles site](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)** (excluding points earned by
  linking SE accounts) from now until Friday, 3pm EST to increase your
  chances of winning **3-FOLD**. See how to earn rep [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

**The Terms:**

- Anyone, anywhere is eligible.
- Winners will be picked at random, with each winner eligible for only
  one prize.
- Winners will be announced Monday, October 24.
- Prizes must be picked up in person at [a licensed Specialized dealer](http://www.specialized.com/zz/en/bc/SBCDealerLocR2.jsp).

**Good luck!**

Comment: Can the prize be picked in the UK? (The link just shows a map of the USA)

Comment: @Ian - Yes. Specialized has authorized dealers across the globe.

Comment: @Ian: http://www.specialized.com/gb/gb/bc/SBCDealerLoc.jsp gives you British Specialized dealers

Comment: I think this is the general "find a dealer anywhere" link: http://www.specialized.com/zz/en/bc/SBCDealerLocR2.jsp

Comment: @freiheit Just FYI, I put in my ZIP code (knowing for a fact I've got nearby Specialized dealers) and it insisted the nearest dealers were in Missouri. It wasn't until I put in my full address I could see the local dealers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

252 Twitterers entered. 12 Stack Exchange users tripled their chances. Now, we have winners!

- Third (Specialized Starter Kit): [**@bckeane**](http://twitter.com/#!/bckeane)
- Second (Specialized Sirrus): [**@C_Y_C_L_I_N_G**](http://twitter.com/#!/c_y_c_l_i_n_g)
- First (Specialized Tricross Sport): [**@nibot**](http://twitter.com/#!/nibot)

Stay tuned for a more in-depth look at the contest statistics published in the meta forum later this week.

Thanks for participating!

Comment: Congratulations! If you three would like to write blog posts about your prizes, let me know. I assume @nibot is user [nibot](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/778/nibot); are the other two site members?

Comment: @CTKeane is [onsite](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/59/ctkeane). I don't believe Brian McFerrin (@C_Y_C_L_I_N_G) is.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! It's perfect, too--I'm moving to Germany next week where I will use this bike as my primary mode of transit!

Answer (score 6):

### Welcome Twitter Visitors!

If you are not familiar with the StackExchange family of sites and  just followed a link here, you may want to click through to [About - Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about) or you can go to the [Bicycles.StackExchange FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq).

We hope you find the Q & A format useful, that you will join, stick around, and help us build the premier bicycling Q & A site on the web.